# in 10 minutes vs 10 minutes later vs 10 minutes after

Tags: word-usage

I heard that you can't say "The train will leave ten minutes later."
Is that true?

Could you please tell me the differences between later, in and after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use *later* to mean *from now*. You can say

> We reached the station at 10.00 and our train left ten minutes later.
>
> The train left after ten minutes.

If you are talking about a future departure, you can say

> The train will leave in ten minutes.
>
> The train will leave ten minutes from now.

Comment: Just for clarity, you can use *10 minutes later* to refer to a future time, or even when it happens to be ten minutes later than now. It's just that the time or event that it's ten minutes later than must be explicitly mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You can say,

*"The bus will leave at 10.30 - The train will leave 10 minutes later."*

This means that the train will leave at 10.30, ***10 minutes later than the bus***